# Inner dependency is not being injected (Weld + JavaSE)

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I am in the process of refactoring an old module, by adding CDI.

I end with

```
public interface ApiFactory {
  ...
}

public class ApiFactorySp
    implements ApiFactory {
  @Inject
  UrlProducer urlProducer;  // <-- Does not get injected
  ...
}
```

and

```
public interface UrlProducer {
    public String getUrl();
}

@Alternative
public class UrlProducerTest
    implements UrlProducer {

    @Override
    public String getUrl() {
        return "https://myTestEnv.mydomain/myWebApp";
    }
 }
```

For testing, I create a `beans.xml` file in `META-INF`:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
  bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <alternatives>
      <class>myOrg.myProject.myPackage.UrlProducerTest</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

To test it, I am doing like shown [in this blog](http://blog.rocketscience.io/dependency-injection-with-cdi-in-java-se/)

```
public class WeldContext {

    public static final WeldContext INSTANCE = new WeldContext();

    private final Weld weld;
    private final WeldContainer container;

    private WeldContext() {
        this.weld = new Weld();
        this.container = weld.initialize();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                weld.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }

    public <T> T getBean(Class<T> type) {
        return container.instance().select(type).get();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class WeldJUnit4Runner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public WeldJUnit4Runner(Class<Object> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createTest() {
        final Class<?> test = getTestClass().getJavaClass();
        return WeldContext.INSTANCE.getBean(test);
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to test the logic, I do

```
@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)
public class MyTest {
     @Inject
     UrlProducer urlProducer;         

     @Inject
     ApiFactory apiFactory;

     @Test
     public void test() {
         apiFactory.doSomethingThatRequiresUrlProducer();
     }
 }
```

When I run this, both of the test attributes are inject, but I get NPE because the `urlProducer` attribute inside of the `apiFactory` instance has not been assigned a value.

Why is Weld not recognizing the `@Inject` attribute inside `ApiFactory`?

JDK 7, Weld 2.2.10, Junit 4.12

UPDATE: After posting the question, started trying with a simpler, brand new project (with just two interfaces and three classes). Using Weld "standalone" did not solve the issue, using [CDI-Unit](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/) did solve it.

Then I modified my original project to use CDI-Unit, but it did not improve anything. After that I change the injection of `UrlProducerTest` in `ApiFactory` from field to constructor (i.e., defining the `@Inject ApiFactory(UrlProducer urlProducer)` constructor) solved it. I still have not tried this solution with "standalone" Weld (that is for tomorrow), but nonetheless I am still interested in know why field injection is not working.

Comment: Are you sure NPE is not because apiFactory is not injected?

Comment: @A.Panzer Yes, I am sure `apiFactory` is injected. But as I was going to reply I thought that I was sure because the code that uses `UrlProducer` is **in the constructor** :-*> and it causes an exception to be thrown during instantiation... I'll have to check it tomorrow, but maybe you want to rewrite your answer to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `UrlProducerTest` is an alternative and you want to inject this bean this class should be added to `beans.xml` into `<alternatives>` tag.

**EDIT**:

I believe if some bean can't be injected you get exception with 'unsatisfied/ambiguous dependencies' message. `Null` could be injected if you used CDI `producer` method that returned null but this is not your scenario.

So if there are no errors in console I have two assumptions:

1. Injection doesn't work at all and you get NPE because `apiFactory` is null
2. You use `urlProducer` before injection. For example, from constructor or initialization block (`apiFactory.doSomethingThatRequiresUrlProducer()` is not provided). So move this logic to some method and annotate it by @PostConstruct

Comment: Well spotted, unfortunately `UrlProducerTest` is declared as an alternative (I modified the names of the classes for simpler versions in the code but left it unmodified in the `beans.xml` file; the `UrlSharepointTest` that appeared in the previous edition was in effect `UrlProducerTest`.

Comment: Indeed, I missed the point that I was using that attribute at the constructor (as I said, I was refactoring some non-CDI code). Obviously, since field injection happens **after** the bean has been created (that is, after the `new` command finishes), I could not use the values of the fields inside the constructor. Moved the logic to a `@PostConstruct` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ApiFactorySp` isn't a CDI bean. You need to annotate the class with `@Named` to identify the class as a CDI bean for CDI to perform dependency injection.

Comment: Thank you, but you are wrong. CDI beans need no annotation; `@Named` may be used for making the bean accessible through EL but is not needed for direct injection: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjfzi.html. Also, from the text of my question, it is clear that the beans are being discovered as such by Weld, since they are injected in my test instance.